# Design button like asus zenphone flashlight widget

Tags: android, flashlight

I know this question is little bit stupid but I want to design a button like power button in flashlight widget in asus zenphone.

When I click power button, it's background change to yellow and it has a some cicle light and run from center to around !!! (I don't know how describe it in English :( )

Please give some suggestion to make effect spillover to around .

Thank in advanced !!

[image: Picture]

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1539335

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)** .

> The ShowcaseView (SCV) library is designed to highlight and showcase
>   specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive
>   overlay. This library is great for pointing out points of interest for
>   users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.

If you're using a Gradle-based project, then you can add SCV as a dependency directly:

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
```

Comment: I thought this library was an overlay, not an animation, like this points out.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073167/how-to-animated-ripple-doted-effect